# TortoiseSVN cleanup failed after failed update

Tags: svn

I tried to do an update on my SVN folder using TortoiseSVN but it failed for some reason. When I tried it again it told me to so the cleanup first so I tried doing that but it's giving me this error:

Cleanup has succesfully processed the following paths: D:\SVN\Code
Cleanup failed to process the following paths: 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp' is not a working copy directory

If I try to do anything else besides running the cleanup command it says that cleanup was interrupted and should be tried again.

I have no idea why it does that since nothing should be linked with the temp folder. I've googled this question and some people had similar issues which I tried the solution for but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest running the `svn cleanup` command via the command line.

I had the exact same error and the command line tool gave me a much better error message (in my case pointing to a file where it didn't have proper access rights).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your working copy is corrupt.  If it doesn't contain any changes you can just delete it and check it out again.  Otherwise, copy the changed files somewhere temporarily, delete and re-checkout the working copy, then copy the changes back.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to perform the cleanup from the commandline.
It indicated there was a file locked, while via the dialog I only got a cryptic error regarding appdata\local\temp. 
I still had a document opened so the cleanup couldn't proceed, closing it and restart the cleanup was enough to solve the issue.